# Infinite loading when trying to add new product

Tags: admin, product-page, magento-2.1.2

As the title say, I cannot add any new product because the page doesn't want to stop loading (See screenshot below). I tryed to disable the cache, tryed with other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera). Still it stays like that (been waiting for more than 10 minutes on the page, nothing change).

I just updated to Magento 2.1.2, so it might be the reason of this issue, even tough I did nothing but running `composer update`.

Thank you.

[image: New Product Infinite Loading]

Comment: Have you checked your Wishlist module is enable or not?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: @Rakesh If you ask about the default Magento Wishlist module, it is enabled. I tryed to disable it from the admin back-end and nothing change. Should I do it from the SSH ?

Comment: @zigojacko Which console ?

Comment: No you have to just enable wishlist module, i have same type of issue faced in past. so i have to ask for to check wishlist module, So you have to check for log file

Comment: @Rakesh Thank you, but I don't really know which log to check and what kind of informations I'm suppose to see.

Comment: you have to check file from var/log, here files are generated which display error if you have any.

Comment: @Cabbi check the console in your browser (F12).

Comment: @Rakesh I have this error in the exception.log : Cannot read contents from file pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/fr_FR/mage/requirejs/mixins.min.js"

Comment: You have to run command, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US fr_FR after run command remove var folder from root and let me know

Comment: @Rakesh Ran both commands but nothing change unfortunately.

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US fr_FR run this command?

Comment: Yes, I did run this command. It took 2-3 minutes. Then I ran rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* to delete the cache. But the page is still loading after that.

Answer (score 0):

Some links in the pub/static/adminhtml might be funked using ssh rm -r the adminhtml directory and it will rebuild itself then flush all cache. hope this helps somebody!